# How do I bypass a firewall using kali linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, security, kali-linux

I started to learn ethical hacking by using kali linux and I'm using multiple virtual machines to achieve an attack into them but I have to disable firewall and antivirus on them to accomplish an attack or exploit.

I was wondering... how do hackers bypass a firewall?
Well... im still learning and I want to accomplish such thing.
any ideas or methods?

thanks

Comment: If there was really a **How to guide**, everybody would start doing it without  having understanding of what they are copy-pasting. First learn, how to build a mouse trap, then learn how to break a mouse trap and then how to build a better mouse.

Comment: It is a very general thing. Firewall is not like a real wall, if you have enough strong explosive, then you can hit a wall on it. A firewall is a complex ruleset in the target computer to drop packets without any examination. Typically, "hacking firewalls" means that we find a way on the *not* filtered channels to ask the machine for which its software isn't ready. It is a way too general "answer", but there is no more clear one, because also your question is too broad.

Comment: What a harsh reaction to a new user's question ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How do hackers bypass a firewall?

- From the inside by tricking  a user into running a piece of malicious code to compromise their system security, or
- From the outside by remotely probing the system, identifying what weaknesses exist, knowing how exploits actually work and then matching the appropriate attack/exploit to the vulnerability found.

How to accomplish this?

The first is relatively easy (especially on your local network) and you will find plenty of 'hacks' online about embedding reverse tcp etc into files. Success relies on the gullibility of your target and while the staff at the Bank of England are not going to fall for it, you can at least practice this on your own phone/spare pc to see how it works.

The second (actual Penetration Testing) is about learning how to probe a systems security measures (firewall etc), find vulnerable (weak) points and to identify how these can be exploited. Understanding and patience are key. It is **not** about launching random exploits and hoping.

Each exploit is tailored to take advantage of a very specific weakness and your exploits fail because the ones you are launching are designed to take advantage of a weakness that simply doesn't exist in your (fire-walled and virus protected) target.

If you are serious about learning 'ethical hacking' then you need to take a step back, understand how to use the tools to probe a system, identify weaknesses and know how to select the exploit(s) appropriate to take advantage of the vulnerabilities that you found.

Tools to learn for starters (and by learn I mean **understanding the meaning of their output**) include

```
nmap/zenmap
armitage
maltego
```

There are plenty of books (like 'Kali Linux 2 Windows Penetration Testing') which will get you started and `openvas` will do a lot of the legwork in gathering information and looking for appropriate exploits. However, until you understand what is actually going on then you will be frustrated.

Last point. You are shooting at a moving target. Old vulnerabilities are being closed daily by system updates etc and [new ones](https://www.rapid7.com/db/) are being found. You need to stay on the bleeding edge to be in the game and if you are running 'msfconsole' 'out of the box' then it is highly unlikely that you will ever find a real world system vulnerable to the exploits you have to hand.